# Can't find the Poly-Edit tool

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was making some tutorials, but I cant find the tool that everyone have. I'm adding a screenshot, where we can see the tutorial with the tools in a blue circle in the left and my unity hub in the right without it. Thank you for your time!

[image]

Comment: Did you load probuilder package?

Answer (score 0):

Probuilder wasn't installed the proper way.

Window -> package manager > Probuilder > install

Comment: I did, but idk why It didnt even show the "tool" to add the pro builder window. :(